# Sql query performance issue - did I screw anything up?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I apologize for the vagueness of the question, but I ran the following query on a production server accidentally (I intended to test it on my local one):

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
GO
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
GO
DECLARE @start DATETIME SET @start = getDate()
EXEC test_1a
SELECT getDate() - @start AS Execution_Time
GO
```

My sql knowledge is just above basic, so I'm not sure what this does. I cancelled the query after I realized I was connected to the wrong machine.

Can someone please explain what these set of statements do and if there is any impact?

Comment: That sounds like it was scary =)  Could you also provide the contents of "test_1a"?  Or are you just worried about the other statements?

Comment: What is the DDL for the proc `test_1a `?

Comment: I don't have that... I actually got it from another sql server posting on StackOverflow. Does this mean that I impacted anything?

Comment: @redFilter, he cleared the cache's anyway so damage done :/

Comment: @SBlacker... how bad of a damage are we talking about?

Comment: @Ray - Nothing permanent but users might notice a sudden drop in performance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.

No permanent damage (assuming the stored procedure didn't do any) but you have just cleared out your entire procedure cache and dropped all non dirty pages from the buffer cache on your production box. (A dirty page is one that has been modified in memory and not yet written out to disc)

This means that the queries that are coming in now will all need to be recompiled (high CPU usage) and that pretty much all data will need to be re-read in from disc.

BTW: I recommend using the free SSMS Tools Pack Addin. You can use the [Window Connection Coloring](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features?f=1#WCC) to give all production server windows a red title bar for example to make this kind of mistake less likely.

[image: SSMS Tools Pack]

Comment: @jadarnel27 There wouldn't be any long term impact, it just means that SQL Server will take a massive performance hit until it has recompiled its execution plans and refilled caches. If nobody has noticed anything yet you probably got away with it.

Comment: @Justin: I think I can because even though it was a prod server, the DB that I accidentally ran this query on is a backup that all the other admins simply move tables to (from other DB where the real work is being done).

Also, as soon as I realized that I was on the prod server, I cancelled it within 10 seconds (at the most). So I know that no rollback is going to happen, but I wonder what can happen in that span of time?

Comment: @Ray - Both of these are server scoped commands not database specific but maybe no-one will notice.

Comment: @Martin Smith - Didn't know that either, so thank you for the clarification. I'm sure some readers would like to know how this story ended. Basically, my stored procedure was just a bunch of select statements, so no damage there. We did some testing with our biggest clients and no lag was observed. Checked the server's CPU usage and hit 60%+ for around an hour, but then dropped to normal levels after that. A happy ending with a slap on the wrist. Thanks to everyone here who helped in preventing me p!$$ in my pants.

Comment: @Justin: Thanks for the explanation.  I had quickly deleted that comment after posting it because I thought it was kind of unnecessary of me to ask =)

Comment: Oh... +1 @Martin Smith for the Window Connection Coloring suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

**Simple answer:** You've cleared all the cached stored procedure plans and they need to be recompiled. The recompiling of the procedures will cause performance issues for a short time.

**No damage has been done.**

**[FREEPROCCACHE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174283.aspx)**

```
Removes all elements from the plan cache, removes a specific plan from the plan 
cache by specifying a plan handle or SQL handle, or removes all cache entries 
associated with a specified resource pool.
```

**[DROPCLEANBUFFERS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187762.aspx)**

```
Removes all clean buffers from the buffer pool.
```

Answer (score -3):

I think ther are not harmfull code as from it's name FREEPROCCACHE and DROPCLEANBUFFERS they are cleaning the cache and the buffer then the rest of the code see the  running time of the procedure.

Comment: Just making sure the buffers are nice and clean :-)

Comment: Read the accepted answer and you will know that "No permanent damage (assuming the stored procedure didn't do any) but you have just cleared out your entire procedure cache and dropped all non dirty pages from the buffer cache on your production box."

Comment: He is new to SQL server and he was afraid that he might have dropped some tables or deleted data by mistake so you should not explain to him how SQL SERVER Engine is working!!

Comment: @Samir - "No permanent damage" isn't the same as "not harmful", for example it'd cause *no permanent damage* here on Stack Overflow...but our sites would be effectively offline for a few minutes while the query cache spools back up.  I'd say that is *harmful*...and yes, we've actually done this, it's not theory.